# Eigen: Best fit of a plane to n points

Tags: c++, 3d, eigen, least-squares

I am just getting in to Eigen, and am trying to fit a plane to a series of 3d points, using an example i found online. My result is always zero, however. i have:

```
template<class Vector3>
std::pair<Vector3, Vector3> best_plane_from_points(const std::vector<Vector3> & c)
{
    // copy coordinates to  matrix in Eigen format
    size_t num_atoms = c.size();
    Eigen::Matrix< Vector3::Scalar, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic > coord(3, num_atoms);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_atoms; ++i) coord.col(i) = c[i];

    // calculate centroid
    Vector3 centroid(coord.row(0).mean(), coord.row(1).mean(), coord.row(2).mean());

    // subtract centroid
    coord.row(0).array() -= centroid(0); coord.row(1).array() -= centroid(1); coord.row(2).array() -= centroid(2);

    // we only need the left-singular matrix here
    //  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99299/best-fitting-plane-given-a-set-of-points

    auto svd = coord.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeThinU | Eigen::ComputeThinV);
    Vector3 plane_normal = svd.matrixU().rightCols<1>();
    std::cout << plane_normal << std::endl;


    return std::make_pair(centroid, plane_normal);

}



void main()
{
    Eigen::Vector3f point1(2, 2, 2);
    Eigen::Vector3f point2(4, 2, 3);
    Eigen::Vector3f point3(4, 2,1);
    Eigen::Vector3f point4(2, 2,3);

    std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> points;

    points.push_back(point1);
    points.push_back(point2);
    points.push_back(point3);
    points.push_back(point4);


    best_plane_from_points(points);

    std::cin.get();
}
```

Is this the right approach to be using here? Or is there a better function in Eigen to do what i want?

To summarize:

I have n points in 3d space. i want to calculate the best fitting plane from these points and return the euler angles of that plane.

thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you asking about a) the math (Should I be using SVD or Method X?); b) if you implemented it correctly; c) coding style?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am asking if this is the best approach to solve this problem, and if so, is this implementation correct?

Comment: The "best" method will depend on what your (real) problem actually is. Another method to consider: [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus) and I'm sure other people can throw in their favorite method.

Comment: It looks correct. You could write it more concisely, e.g. `Vector3 centroid = coord.rowwise().mean();` and `coord.colwise() -= centroid;`

Comment: ok thanks. I will look into RANSAC also. in the above code `plane_normal` always returns as 0,1,0. This seems wrong to me, or would that be expected? (I am also struggling to get my brain around getting rotation angles as degrees from a normal vector) Thanks again!

Comment: Of course it always prints {0,1,0}. All four of the points are on the plane where y=2, hence the normal vector is x=0,y=1,z=0. I don't understand how rotations figure into this question...

Comment: Ah I see. Rotations figure, because i need to find the euler angles of the plane, from this result.  Are you aware of a method to do thi?

Comment: A plane has no Euler angles. They are ill-defined. You can only obtain 2 angles, not free, from a plane (except if you consider a particular base of your plane).

Comment: I see. Thank you. That makes more sense to me. Actually i only need two angles, as yaw is not a factor. How can i get these two angles, from my ABCD plane?

Comment: Thanks! Now that i know i am looking to get 2 angles instead of three, I have it working with this code:

`float angle = atan2(x, y) * 180 / PI;
 float angle2 = atan2(z,y) * 180 / PI;`

Thank you again for the nudge in the right direction.